# 3ware 9650se raid6 replaced with larger drives

Tags: 3ware, raid6

I'have been running a setup with 8 drives, each 2TB by now (raid6). I started to build up the setup with 1.5TB drives back few years ago and slowly added and replaced all drives to 2 TB. Now the last rebuild has been done and wanted to upgrade the size of the unit from 8.1TB to 11TB in Raid6 but i cannot do the migration as it says source and destination would be the same...

How can I resize the unit online please?
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Rgds
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Through tw_cli you can only grow logical size by adding new drives (by migrate command), but seems not for already used disks.

I don`t sure (don`t have such controller for test now), but you can try to migrate raid6 to 6 drives and then expands the array to 8.